# Looking for a not measurable function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers, measurable-functions

I'm looking for a counter example as simple as possible.

I've learned that if X is a stochastic variable, it holds that
\begin{align}E[X | X] = X E[1 | X]\qquad (1) \end{align} 
since X is measurable with regards to it's own sigma-algebra. 
Moreover I have that
\begin{align}E[f(X)  | X] = f(X) E[1 | X] \qquad (2) \end{align} 
if $f$ is measurable function.

I'm looking for some kind of setup where (2) isn't true.

Comment: If you can find a non-measurable set then you can easily define a non-measurable function.  I think that non-measurable sets are necessarily fairly weird.  One is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set.  That example uses the axiom of choice, maybe they all need that (but I have not checked).

Comment: Reading my own link, I see the answer.  "In 1970, Solovay demonstrated that the existence of a non-measurable set for the Lebesgue measure is not provable within the framework of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory in the absence of the Axiom of Choice."